# What is the query to get column name?

Tags: android, sql, database, android-listview

```
|Title  | Subcategory | Details | 
|-------------------------------|
|Song   | TAMIL SONG  |  Yuvan  |    
|-------------------------------|
|Song   | English    |Tom       | 
|-------------------------------|
|Movie  | mal         | abcd    | 
|-------------------------------|
|Movie  | Telugu     |TomCuirse | 
|-------------------------------|
|Sounds  | mal         | abcd   |
```

I have a list of column names like this. I want to display the Subcategory fields based on the selection of Title. How can we write a query for this and how can we attach this to ArrayAdapter on listview? the datas canot be displyed in listview the textview is empty but the listview is available

Subcategor Class

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.subcategory_layout);
    listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);

    //Intent i = getIntent();

    dbHelper = new SqlLiteDbHelper(this);
    try {
        dbHelper.openDataBase();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    sqLiteDatabase=dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor=dbHelper.getsubcategory(sqLiteDatabase);
    subcategoryAdapter = new SubcategoryAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.sublist_item);
    listView.setAdapter(subcategoryAdapter);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            String subcategory;
            subcategory=cursor.getString(0);
            foodSupply= new FoodSupply(subcategory);
            subcategoryAdapter.add(foodSupply);

        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }enter code here
```

SubcategoryAdapter

```
public class SubcategoryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
List list = new ArrayList();
public SubcategoryAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}





    @Override
    public void add (Object object){
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}
    static class LayoutHandler {
        TextView SUBCATEGORY;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount () {
    return list.size();
}

    @Override
    public Object getItem ( int position){
    return list.get(position);
}

    @Override
    public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    View row = convertView;
    LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sublist_item, parent, false);
        layoutHandler = new LayoutHandler();
        layoutHandler.SUBCATEGORY = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        row.setTag(layoutHandler);
    } else {
        layoutHandler = (LayoutHandler) row.getTag();
    }
    FoodSupply foodSupply = (FoodSupply) this.getItem(position);
    layoutHandler.SUBCATEGORY.setText(foodSupply.getSubcategory());
    return row;
}enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the 'Where Params' to select what you wish to return from query. Get the cursor like so

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("Your_table_name", "Subcategory", "Title = ?", new String[] { "Song" }, "", "", "");
```

Then you iterate over it:

```
while(cursor.moveToNext()) {
    String subCategory = cursor.getString(0);
}
```

After that you can store the subCategory in a list and insert that into an ArrayAdapter.

Comment: Thanks But when i click Title Name in listview the subcategory fields related to that title name want to display in another listview !! so we want to use  cursor in that setOnItemClickListener ??

Comment: You can click the title and then insert it into the query on the onItemClickListener if that matches your use case. The above code is just means for you to get a list of subcategories, how you use it afterwards is up to you.

Comment: Fields are Already Inserted!!i simply want to display the Column names in listview..i already display a title in a listview using Arrayadapter with custom layout now when click that title the fields related to that titles are want to display in a new Activity...plz help 3,4 days i m lock there and i dont now how to do it :(

Comment: but you know the name of the columns when you create the database. They are always going to be fixed values so you don't need a method to do it. My answer shows you how to select all the subcategory fields from the db where the title matches the given string, which answers the question. If it doesn't help you, you need to make the question clearer.

Comment: thanks when i click the title in listview..the title related subcategory are display this is what i asked But i have a problem..the problem is i have a custom layout with a Single Textview..the datas in that column name is not display in my listview

Comment: Check my Updated Code..listview will display but in textview datas will not set it show empty colums in textview @Rob